# codeigniter: login form using ajax probelm

Tags: codeigniter

This is my login code in codeigniter...its not getting logged in only it shows the result in jquery response?whats wrong with this code?
I have written controller,model and have used jquery for this.

**controller(login.php)page**

```
function validate_credentials(){

        $username =  $this->input->post('username');
        $password =  $this->input->post('passwd');

        $data = $this->login_model->validate();

        if($data){

            $this->session->set_userdata('username',$data); 
            redirect('site/math_page');

        }
        else{
            echo'something went wrong';
        }


    }
```

**Model(login_model.php)page**

```
function validate() {

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('user_details');
        // $this->db->where('user_email',$email);
        // $this->db->where('user_password',$pass);

            if($query=$this->db->get())
            {
                return $query->result_array();
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }

    }
```

**login jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        //login js..
        $("#login_submit").click(function(){
            var username = $("#username").val().trim();
            var passwd = $("#passwd").val().trim();
            //alert(username);
            if( username == "" && passwd == "" ) {
                $(".lognerror").html("Please enter  Login credentials!");
                $(".lognerror").show().fadeOut(3000);
            }
            else if( username == "" ) {
                $(".usererror").html("Please enter username");
                $(".usererror").show().fadeOut(3000);
            }
            else if ( passwd == "" ) {
                $(".passwrderr").html("Please Enter Password");
                $(".passwrderr").show().fadeOut(3000);
            }
            else {

                $.ajax({
                    url: base_url+'index.php/login/validate_credentials',
                    data:{username:username,passwd:passwd},
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (response) {
                        // do something with the result
                         //var msg = "";
                        //alert(msg);
                         if(response == 1){
                            window.location.href= base_url+'index.php/site/math_page';
                        }
                        else {
                            msg = "Invalid Login credentials!";
                        }
                        //$("#message").html(msg); 
                        $("#message").show().fadeOut(3000); 
                    }
                });
            }
        });
});
```

can someone tell me what's wrong with this code.I am new to php so kindly guide me through this

Comment: Send $username and $password as a parameter in validate(). And apply where clause in the model. And use $query->num_rows() > 0 in IF condition.

Comment: You should not redirect from the controller, send the response to jquery instead.

Answer (score 1):

Send $username and $password as a parameter in validate(). And apply where clause in the model. And use $query->num_rows() > 0 in IF condition.

In Model -

```
function validate($email, $pass) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('user_details');
    $this->db->where('user_email',$email);
    $this->db->where('user_password',$pass);
    $query=$this->db->get()
    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
       return $query->result_array();
    }
    else{
       return false;
    }
 }
```

In Controller -

Replace

`$data = $this->login_model->validate();`

With

`$data = $this->login_model->validate($username, $password);`

Change your response in controller

```
    if($data){
        $this->session->set_userdata('username',$data); 
        echo 1;
    }
    else{
        echo 0;
    }
```